# Scheduling Timer / optimizing TimerTask (Kotlin)

Tags: timer, timertask

Please consider the following:

```kotlin
var everySunday = Timer()
var timertask = object: TimerTask(){
    override fun run(){
         var day = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
         var time = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date()
         var midnight = "00:00:00"
         if (day == Calendar.Sunday && time == midnight){
               Toast.makeText(this, "It's Sunday!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
         }
}

everySunday.scheduleAtFixedRate(timertask, 0, 60000)
```

Basically everySunday's function is to inform me that it's Sunday every time it's 12:00 am in Sunday.

However, I would like to simplify everySunday's code further to just this:

```kotlin
var everySunday = Timer()
var timertask = object: TimerTask(){
    override fun run(){
         Toast.makeText(this, "It's Sunday!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

//val date = ??  <-- "Sunday 12:00 am" 
everySunday.schedule(timertask, date)
```

The problem is I want to write date as a Date! type that represents Sunday 12:00am but I am not sure how to do it. Assistance would be much appreciated.